# how use jdbc to write testable service/dao with transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, mocking

these days I write some code without spring support, and try write code like this In Service..

```
c = ds.getConnection();
c.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    dao.findXX(c, id);
    c.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    c.rollback();
}
```

but, I meet some problem when I try to mock DAO, and test my service.
because getConnection is called, it will connect to a db which doesn't want to see for our.

how to write service/dao with jdbc to easy test?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use one of in-memory databases (HSQL, Derby, H2).
When test starts you just create connection to in-memory db and mock your `ds` so it returns this connection when getConnection is called.

Use one of these connection strings:

```
public static final String JDBC_URL_DERBY = "jdbc:derby:memory:some_db_name;drop=true";
public static final String JDBC_URL_HSQL = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:some_db_name;shutdown=true";
public static final String JDBC_URL_H2 = "jdbc:h2:mem:some_db_name";
```

all of these connections create in-memory db instance with name *some_db_name*